# variable scope of a HashMap

Tags: java, variables, scope, hashmap

I use following code to populate a HashMap within a try-catch block, and indeed is populated fine.
The problem is that outside the try-catch block, it appears to be empty. 
Is it a variable scope definition issue? It may be very simple, but I am stuck, please some help.

```
   public class Degrees {

   HashMap<String,String> HM = new HashMap<String,String> ();

   public static void main(String[] args) {

          try ....
            HM.put(Integer.toString(users),Integer.toString(counter));
            System.out.println("HMsize:" + HM.size());
          catch ....

          try ...
          System.out.println("HMsize:" + HM.size()); ---> appears 0
          catch ...
```

Comment: post your actual code

Comment: You should declare a `Map`, not a `HashMap`: `Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();`

Comment: I think multiple catch blocks like this are bad style.  If this is an example, it's a poor one.

Comment: This code wouldn't even compile. Post the actual code, if you want us to spot the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

The main method is Static (i.e. one instance per class), the HashMap is not static, that means you will have to instantiate the method.

WHat would work, but DON'T DO that

```
public class Degrees {

   private static HashMap<String,String> HM = new HashMap<String,String> ();
```

Using static variables is usually a very bad design which may lead to errors when the class is used on more places.

What you probably want to do is defining the map in scope of the class:

```
public class Degrees {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String,String> HM = new HashMap<String,String> ();
        try ....
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code will not compile because non static variable HashMap cannot be referenced in static context.Make sure try to add static modifier to HashMap.

```
    private static HashMap<String,String> HM = new HashMap<String,String> ();
```